# haml using variable in rails layout for meta keywords

Tags: haml

We would like to adjust the meta keywords of a web page based upon the specific action. As a novice at haml, is there a way that this could be done via a `provides` statement. For example:

in client.html.haml

```
- provide(:keywords, 'here are unique keywords')
```

and in our application.html.haml, how would we do this? Like:

```
%meta{ name: "keywords", content:  #{yield(:keywords)} ||= default keywords
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say *why* your approach doesn't work, so I'm going to guess it's a syntax error in your haml (missing closing bracket). Also, I'm not sure what `default keywords` is or why you're using the `||=` operator - either of those may also be causing your solution to "not work".

Something like the following will work as expected:

```
# application.html.haml
%meta{ name: "keywords", |
       content: content_for?(:keywords) ? yield(:keywords) : "default" }
       # this could also be achieved using content_for?(:keywords) || "default"

# client.html.haml
- provide :keywords do
  this should work
```